# Empty output in app with named pipes

Tags: c++, linux, pipe

I have a question about named pipes in C++ on linux. I have three apps. I run all of them. Each app must be write his PID to channel called "first", "second" or "third". Then application reads the contents of the other two channels and displays it on the screen.

Output example for FIRST app:

"#1 pid - 2000" //his PID

"Readed #2 pid - 3000" //PIDs of others

"Readed #3 pid - 5000" //PIDs of others

Output example for FIRST app:
"#2 pid - 3000" 
"Readed #1 pid - 2000"
"Readed #3 pid - 5000"

All of apps contains similar code like this(first app):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char s1[15],s2[15],s3[15] ;

int fd1,fd2,fd3;

unlink("first") ;

if(mkfifo("first", S_IFIFO|0666)==-1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error creating first\n");
    exit(0);
}

if(fd1=open("first",O_WRONLY)==-1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening first\n");
    exit(0);
}

sprintf(s1,"#1 pid=%d", getpid());
write(fd1,&s1,sizeof(s1)) ;
printf("#1 pid=%d", getpid());
if(fd2=open("second",O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)==-1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening second\n");
    exit(0);
}
else
{ 
    if(read(fd2, &s2, 15)==-1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading second\n");
    else
        fprintf(stdout,"\nReaded - #2 pid - %s", s2);

}


if(fd3=open("third",O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)==-1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening third\n");
    exit(0);
}
else
{ 
    if(read(fd3, &s3, 15)==-1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading third\n");
    else
        fprintf(stdout,"\nReaded - #3 pid - %s", s3);

}

close(fd1) ; close(fd2); close(fd3);
return 1 ;
}
```

But I have no output! When I run the first application, I expect to see anything like this "#1 pid is 1000", but there is nothing. When I run the second app I expect to see there "#2 pis is 2000" and in the first app must be append "#2 pid is 2000". Output of ALL apps is empty! Where is an error? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Comment

You should really have a single program for all three processes, which takes 3 arguments.  For sake of argument, the first argument is the FIFO that the process should create, and the other two are the ones it should read.  You can then run:

```
./your_prog first second third &
./your_prog second third first &
./your_prog third first second &
```

However, if you like the idea of maintaining three almost identical programs instead of one, then that's your problem, not mine.

Also, why is this question tagged 'C++' when the code is pure C code?

#### Bugs

1. You really need to write the PID twice, so that each of the other two processes can read it.
2. You need to fix your tests on the file descriptors.  Your code looks like:

   ```
   if(fd2=open("second",O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)==-1)
   ```

   It should be:

   ```
   if ((fd2 = open("second", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)) == -1)
   ```

   At the moment, you're getting 0 or 1 assigned to your file descriptors because the compiler treats it as though you've written:

   ```
   if (fd2 = (open("second", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) == -1))
   ```
3. You're then left with a timing problem.  The [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) calls are non-blocking (because you opened the FIFO with O_NONBLOCK), so they return -1 with `errno` set to `EAGAIN` when there's no data ready to read.  Maybe you should change the mode to blocking after the file is open (a pair of `fcntl()` calls, IIRC), or you need to loop until you read some input, preferably with a sub-second delay in the loop, or you may be able to use `poll()` or `select()` to wait for input (but be careful: O_NONBLOCK may screw those up).

Comment: I can not use one application, I need separate to three programs(by task)

Comment: OK; have fun fixing the same bugs three times over.  It will be a good learning exercise in copy and paste, or something.  Generally, it is better to avoid writing almost identical code three times.  If it is hard to get one right, then getting all three consistent (and right) is harder still.  The analysis of the bugs remains valid.

Comment: The fact that you need three separate processes running does not mean that you need three separate pieces of code.  It doesn't even mean that you need three distinct executables.  And getting 3 distinct executables also does not require 3 distinct pieces of source code.